# Deleting a non-unique procedure on DB2

Tags: sql, db2, procedure

In my attempts to edit a procedure using the line

```
CREATE OR DROP PROCEDURE
```

I have created two procedures with the same name, how can I delete them?

The error I receive whenever I attempt to drop it is

> Reference to Rountine BT_CU_ODOMETER was made without a signature, but the routine is not unique in its schema.
>       SQLSTATE = 42725

I am using DB2

Comment: What DB2 version/platform?

Comment: "create or **drop**" does not make any sense to me. Do you maybe mean "create or **replace**"?

Comment: Yes, sorry create or replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming this is DB2 for LUW.

DB2 allows you to "overload" procedures with the same name but different number of parameters. Each procedure receives a *specific name*, which can be provided by you or generated by the system and which will be unique.

To determine the specific names of your procedures, run

```
SELECT ROUTINESCHEMA, ROUTINENAME, SPECIFICNAME FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINENAME = 'BT_CU_ODOMETER'
```

You can then drop each procedure individually:

```
DROP SPECIFIC PROCEDURE <specific name>
```

Answer (score 2):

**PROBLEM**

When multiple stored procedures are created with the same name but with a different number of parameters, then the stored procedure is considered overloaded. When attempting to drop an overloaded stored procedure using the DROP PROCEDURE statement, the following error could result:

```
db2 drop procedure SCHEMA.PROCEDURENAME
```

DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned: SQL0476N  Reference to routine "SCHEMA.PROCEDURENAME" was made without a signature, but the routine is not unique in its schema.  SQLSTATE=42725

**CAUSE**

The error is returned because the stored procedure is overloaded and therefore the procedure is not unique in that schema. To drop the procedure you must specify the data types that were specified on the CREATE PROCEDURE statement or use the stored procedure's specific name per the examples below.

**SOLUTION**

In order to drop an overloaded stored procedure you can use either of the following statements:

```
 db2 "DROP PROCEDURE procedure-name(int, varchar(12))" 
 db2 "DROP SPECIFIC PROCEDURE specific-name"
```

Note: The specific-name can be identified by selecting the SPECIFICNAME column from syscat.routines catalog view.

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to drop *all* the overloads of a given procedure name, here's a handy script based on [mustaccio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36947612/521799)

```
BEGIN
  FOR rec AS 
    SELECT SPECIFICNAME, ROUTINETYPE
    FROM SYSCAT.ROUTINES
    WHERE ROUTINENAME = 'ROUTINE_NAME'
  DO
    IF rec.ROUTINETYPE = 'P' THEN
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SPECIFIC PROCEDURE ' || rec.SPECIFICNAME;
    ELSE
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP SPECIFIC FUNCTION ' || rec.SPECIFICNAME;
    END IF;
  END FOR;
END
```

Answer (score -1):

A procedure can be dropped like:

DROP PROCEDURE INORUP RESTRICT;
The parameter RESTRICT is required. It avoids dropping a procedure used by a trigger. The procedure package is dropped.
Packages and plans calling the procedure are invalidated.

Comment: isn't the problem that he has two with the same name -- you have to drop it object id.